# Exception for ModRewrite redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, exception, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using the following few line in my .htaccess file to redirect from every `/something` to `/#!/something` url. So I'm redirecting to a hash so I can catch it with javascript. That works perfectly fine …

```
RewriteEngine on
# not existing file (images, css, etc)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# no query parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
# not /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
# R=redirect, NE=dont escape #, L=last rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#!/$1 [R,NE,L]
# same but with query parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?%{QUERY_STRING}#!/$1 [R,NE,L]
```

Is there a way to have an exception on that. E.g. when I enter `www.test.com/stats` I don't want that to happen!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this in front of all the rules you want the exception on:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stats
```

And any other URI's you don't want to redirect. You can include them all in the same regex:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(stats|something|example|test)
```

Comment: thank you, but where exactly do I put this line? You said above every rule I want the exception on. Since I already got help with the first lines of my modrewrite I need a little bit more detail where I put this line.

Comment: @Matt Add it just above the two lines containing `RewriteRule ...`